# Percentile for Each Observation w/r/t Grouping Variable

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like the following. It is grouped by variable "Year" and I want to extract the percentiles of *each* observation of Score, with respect to the Year it is from, preferably as a vector.

```
Year   Score
2001   89
2001   70
2001   72
2001   ...
..........
2004   87
2004   90
```

etc.

How can I do this? aggregate will not work, and I do not think apply will work either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following up on Vince's solution, you can also do this with `plyr` or `by`:

```
ddply(df, .(years), function(x) transform(x, percentile=ecdf(x$scores)(x$scores)))
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I knew there had to be a one-line way to do this, even if it requires loading a package.

Comment: Or a little more simply: `ddply(df, .(years), transform,  percentile = ecdf(scores)(scores))`

Answer (score 9):

Using `ave`

```
ave(d1$scores, d1$year, FUN=function(x) ecdf(x)(x))
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution - it uses a function from stats and is oneline. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding, but I think it can be done this way:

```
> years = c(2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001)
> scores = c(13, 65, 23, 34, 78, 56, 89, 98, 100)
> tapply(scores, years, quantile)
$`2001`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  56   78   89   98  100 

$`2006`
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
13.00 20.50 28.50 41.75 65.00
```

Is this right?

> I mean the actual percentile of each
>   observation. – Ryan Rosario

Edit:

I think this may do it then:

```
> tapply(scores, years, function(x) { f = ecdf(x); sapply(x, f) })
$`2001`
[1] 0.4 0.2 0.6 0.8 1.0

$`2006`
[1] 0.25 1.00 0.50 0.75
```

With your data:

```
> tapply(scores, years, function(x) { f = ecdf(x); sapply(x, f) })
$`2000`
[1] 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000

$`2008`
[1] 0.5 1.0
```

Edit 2:

This is probably faster:

```
tapply(scores, years, function(x) { f = ecdf(x); f(x) })
```

`f()` is vectorized :-)

Last, modification, I promise :-). If you want names:

```
> tapply(scores, years, function(x) { f = ecdf(x); r = f(x); names(r) <- x; r })
$`2000`
     1000      1700      2000 
0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000 

$`2008`
1500 2000 
 0.5  1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using data.table is pretty straight-forward as well. Just for completeness and also as an easy way to find the data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
year <- rep(2001:2005, 2)
score <- round(rnorm(10, 35, 3))

dt <- data.table(year, score)


dt[, .(Percentile = ecdf(score)(score)), by = list(year)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
# first I'll create two dummy variables (Year, Score)
year <- rep(2001:2005, 2)
score <- round(rnorm(10, 35, 3))

# then coerce variables to data frame
d <- data.frame(year, score)

# then you can use split() function to apply
# function to each stratum of grouping variable
sapply(split(score, year), function(x) quantile(x, probs=seq(.1, .9, .1)))
```

Output will go something like this:

```
     2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
10%  34.3 32.1 34.3 29.6 36.1
20%  34.6 32.2 34.6 30.2 36.2
30%  34.9 32.3 34.9 30.8 36.3
40%  35.2 32.4 35.2 31.4 36.4
50%  35.5 32.5 35.5 32.0 36.5
60%  35.8 32.6 35.8 32.6 36.6
70%  36.1 32.7 36.1 33.2 36.7
80%  36.4 32.8 36.4 33.8 36.8
90%  36.7 32.9 36.7 34.4 36.9
```

You can utilize t() function to transpose rows and columns if you prefer. Writing a function will be a good way to tackle this kind of problems. I strongly recommend plyr package written by Hadley Wickam.

Hope this helps!
All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I found a method, but it requires a loop.

```
group.pctiles <- function(group.var, comparable) {
    unique.vals <- unique(group.var)
    pctiles <- vector(length = length(group.var))
    for (i in 1:length(unique.vals)) {
        slice <- which(group.var == unique.vals[i])
        F <- ecdf(comparable[slice])
        group.pctiles <- F(comparable[slice])
        pctiles[slice] <- group.pctiles
    }
    return(pctiles)
}
```

group.var is the variable that groups the data. In my example in my question, it is Year. comparable contains the values we want to find the percentiles for. In my question, comparable would be Score.

For the following data, I get the result below:

```
Year,School,Fees
2000,10,1000
2008,1,1050
2008,4,2000
2000,3,1700
2000,1,2000

> group.pctiles(dat, dat$Year, dat$Fees)
[1] 0.3333333 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000
```

Then, I can cbind these percentiles back into the original data.frame for analysis, reporting, etc.

Anyone have a solution that doesn't require a loop?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
Year <- c(2000,2008,2008,2000,2000)
Fees <- c(1000,1050,2000,1700,2000)
dat <- data.frame(Fees,Year,result=NA)
res <- tapply(Fees,Year,function(x) rank(x,ties.method="max")/length(x))
for(i in 1:length(res))
   dat[Year==as.numeric(names(res)[i]),"result"] <-res[[i]]
```

which yields:

```
  Fees Year    result
1 1000 2000 0.3333333
2 1050 2008 0.5000000
3 2000 2008 1.0000000
4 1700 2000 0.6666667
5 2000 2000 1.0000000
```